# Calculate the limit with min in the denominator

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x,y\to 0,0}= \frac{(|xy|)}{\min(x^4,y^4)}$.

I don't know how to solve it. can someone help? ${{}}$

Comment: The $min$ is the *minimum* of the two numbers inside the bracket. Now can you handle the expression?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I know, i dont know how to solve it

Comment: Your question says " I don't understand what is the meaning of the min" so I answered that. Anyway, about the question itself : the expression is always bigger than $\frac{|xy|}{x^4}$ and $\frac{|xy|}{y^4}$ : now what can you say about these expressions as $x,y$ approach $0,0$ ?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг how the expression is always bigget than $\frac{|xy|}{x^4}$ and  $\frac{|xy|}{y^4}$  ??

Comment: Because $\min\{x^4,y^4\}$ is smaller than both $x^4$ and $y^4$. So if the denominator is made smaller, the fraction as a whole becomes bigger right? Making the denominator $x^4$ or $y^4$ increases it, so the whole fraction becomes smaller. The point is, the new fractions are easier to analyse because of cancellations.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes.

Comment: Now the ball is in your court : you have to analyse $\frac{|xy|}{x^4}$ as $x,y$ approach $0,0$, similarly $\frac{|xy|}{y^4}$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг its $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: Right, except that when you choose how to approach $0$, the limit changes. Approach $0,0$ along the path $y = x^4$ with $x > 0$, the limit is then $0$. But if you approach along $y = x^3$ then the limit is $1$, if you approach along $y=x$ then the limit is infinite. So the limit is different each time. This suggests that the initial limit should also potentially not exist.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thank you very much. may I ask you more questions in private? have an exam tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, yes, you can. We will do it in the comments after the question. If you wish to ask a separate question, you can do that (but keep good standard!) and can call me there. If the doubts are small and niggly then we will sort it in the comments. But only half an hour, unfortunately : I've to sleep in some time (correction : seeing your predicament, make it 90 minutes).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thank you go to sleep ill get along.

Comment: I am writing your answer, I will finish then we can decide.

Comment: I have written an answer, kindly seek clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is always infinite.

This is because the given expression, as I pointed out in the comments, is bigger than both $\frac{|xy|}{y^4}$ and $\frac{|xy|}{x^4}$.

Now, the point is :
$$
\frac{|xy|}{y^4} \times \frac{|xy|}{x^4} = \frac{1}{x^2y^2}
$$

after cancellations. Therefore, if $x,y \to (0,0)$, then at least one of the expressions in the product on the LHS is bigger than $\frac 1{|xy|}$ (if both were smaller than $\frac 1{|xy|}$, their product would be smaller than $\frac{1}{x^2y^2}$ but it is equal by the above line, so we have a contradiction.)

Therefore, we conclude that $$
\frac{|xy|}{\min\{x^4,y^4\}} \geq \frac 1{|xy|}
$$

As $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ , clearly $\frac 1{|xy|}$ has limit infinite (write it as $\frac 1{|x|} \frac 1{|y|}$) so the answer is infinite as well (I don't know if the terminology differs, but  you could also say the limit "doesn't exist").

Answer (score 0):

Take $y=x\ne0$ and

$$\frac{|xy|}{\min(x^4,y^4)}=\frac{x^2}{x^4}=\frac1{x^2}.$$

What do you think ?

Comment: infinity! can be +infinity, and can be -infinity

Comment: @LorinSherry: with positive-only terms, $-\infty$ will be difficult… But what about $y=x^3$ ?